# Regularisers in Keras vs. Caffe

Tags: neural-network, theano, conv-neural-network, keras

I've edited an AlexNet in KERAS, trying to learn a single class (i.e. dogs/faces or not dog/faces).
I have training samples of **correct** images so the Ytrain is **[1, 0]**, and **incorrect** images so the Ytrain is **[0,1]**.
The goal is to know if the image is a dog (for example).

while training the loss was very big ~ 100,000,000

so i deleted the regularisers lines and it worked...

```
activity_regularizer=ActivityRegularizer(l1=1, l2=1),
W_regularizer=WeightRegularizer(l1=2.0,l2=0.0)))
```

In Caffe the model works fine with these lines in the convolution layers:

```
param {
  lr_mult: 1
  decay_mult: 1
}
param {
  lr_mult: 2
  decay_mult: 0
}
```

Here is the model in Keras(image size 3,68,56):

```
    Xtrain = self.Xtrain
    Ytrain = self.Ytrain

    batch_size = 10
    nb_classes = 2
    nb_epoch = 3

    # input image dimensions
    img_rows, img_cols = np.shape(self.Xtrain)[2], np.shape(self.Xtrain)[3]
    #########################
    ###   AlexNet - Start  ##
    #########################
    print("Defining AlexNet...")

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=(3,img_rows,img_cols)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(96, 11, 11, border_mode='valid',
                            init='glorot_normal',
                            activation='relu',
                            activity_regularizer=ActivityRegularizer(l1=1, l2=1),
                            W_regularizer=WeightRegularizer(l1=2.0,l2=0.0)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 5, 5, border_mode='valid',
                            init='glorot_normal',
                            activation='relu',
                            activity_regularizer=ActivityRegularizer(l1=1, l2=1),
                            W_regularizer=WeightRegularizer(l1=2,l2=0)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(384, 3, 3, border_mode='valid',
                            init='glorot_normal',
                            activation='relu',
                            activity_regularizer=ActivityRegularizer(l1=1, l2=1),
                            W_regularizer=WeightRegularizer(l1=2,l2=0)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(384, 3, 3, border_mode='valid',
                            init='glorot_normal',
                            activation='relu',
                            activity_regularizer=ActivityRegularizer(l1=1, l2=1),
                            W_regularizer=WeightRegularizer(l1=2,l2=0)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='valid',
                            init='glorot_normal',
                            activation='relu',
                            activity_regularizer=ActivityRegularizer(l1=1, l2=1),
                            W_regularizer=WeightRegularizer(l1=2,l2=0)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(4096,
                    activation='relu',
                    init='glorot_normal',
                    activity_regularizer=ActivityRegularizer(l1=1, l2=1),
                    W_regularizer=WeightRegularizer(l1=2,l2=0)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(4096,
                    activation='relu',
                    init='glorot_normal',
                    activity_regularizer=ActivityRegularizer(l1=1, l2=1),
                    W_regularizer=WeightRegularizer(l1=2,l2=0)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))


    model.add(Dense(nb_classes,
                    activation='softmax',
                    activity_regularizer=ActivityRegularizer(l1=1, l2=1),
                    W_regularizer=WeightRegularizer(l1=2,l2=0)))

    #######################
    ###   AlexNet - End  ##
    #######################

    add = Adadelta(lr=0.1, rho=0.95, epsilon=1e-06, decay=0.995)
    print("Compiling AlexNet...")
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=add)

    print("Fitting AlexNet...")
    model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
      show_accuracy=True, verbose=1, shuffle=True)
```

Y is that??

Comment: Did you try with a simple SGD as optimizer with a small learning rate?

Comment: OK, so the problem was that those lines where making the problem:  
`activity_regularizer=ActivityRegularizer(l1=1, l2=1),  
W_regularizer=WeightRegularizer(l1=2,l2=0)))`  
  
and the Question now is - Y?. it was suppose to work like in Caffe:

  `param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }`  

am i wrong??

Comment: Keras regularizers are totally different from the layer-wise learning rates in Caffe. They add new regularization terms to the loss. See [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/65b5899d068daadb9101025dd8b8a7e4ceecec35/keras/regularizers.py#L28-L29) and [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/65b5899d068daadb9101025dd8b8a7e4ceecec35/keras/regularizers.py#L48-L49).